# Flutter Firestore Can I create collections using a Map

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

my question is, can I create 1 document in multiple collections using a single:

```
firestore
  .collection('map')
  .doc('documentvariable')
  .set(data());
```

Where instead "map" would be an actual **Map** with list of String names for collections into which I would like to add the document.
Reason why I chose a **Map** is because I need to be able to add more and more collections to it using UI.
Is it possible and if so is there a better solution for this?

Comment: I think (my opinion) you cant create/write 1 document in multiple collection with just one query. Youll need to iterate to those collections names. But in cloud_firestore you can find/read/get a document with the same collection name directly by using collectionGroup query.

Comment: Simply loop over all the elements in your map, and have each loop-element set as the argument for the collection(your_element).

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible as **.collection only accept a String.**  As others mentioned in the comments you can simply iterate through the list of collection names you want to add the document to. Something like this.

```
List<String> allCollectionNamesYouWant = ['collection1', 'collection2'];

    for(String collectionName in allCollectionNamesYouWant){
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(collectionName)
          .doc('documentvariable')
          .set(data());
      }
```